# Django 1.5 compilemessages fails

Tags: django, localization, django-1.5

Trying to run `$ python manage.py compilemessages` fails in Django 1.5.2.

Returns
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 35: ordinal not in range(128)`

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your project settings. It might be that your `LOCALE_PATHS` or `LANGUAGES` setting contains non-unicode strings.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are not forgetting the comma at the end of the `LOCALE_PATHS`, should be like this:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'locale'),
)
```

If doesnt work, open the `compilemessages.py` file and print your `basedir` and the files. Maybe you have forgot to add `# coding: utf-8` to the top of a file or your basedir is incorrect.